# Kotlin Pass Object Class as Parameter Initialize

Tags: java, android, android-studio, object, kotlin

I need to pass as parameter **SQLiteDatabase** class/object to let execSQL act. In *SQL_User* , is included with extended SQLiteOpenHelper.... But how I initialize that on *DatabaseActivity*

I think I don't understand at all what's the way to go with this...

```
class DatabaseActivity : Activity {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      val db = Sql_User(this, "Users", null, 1)

      // Here I get an error on ??, anything I think could works doesn'ts
      if (db != null) { Sql_User.insert( «??» , "1", "DefaultUser") }

   }
}


class Sql_User : SQLiteOpenHelper {
    companion object {
        fun insert(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: String, p2: String){ p0!!.execSQL("INSERT INTO Users ( id_user, username ) VALUES ('${p1}, '${p2}')") 
    }

    ...
}
```

The error I get on that line, any parameter I pass is ... **Classifier SQLiteDatabase does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here**

Comment: According to the error message, you’re simply passing`SQLiteDatabase`, right? You have to pass an instance of that class instead. Therefore an object of SQLiteDatabase needs to be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `db` variable is of type `SQLOpenHelper` not `SQLiteDatabase`.  To get a database from the helper, you need to call the [`getWritableDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) method (or `writeableDatabase` property in kotlin) to get a database.

So for you, something like --

```
 Sql_User.insert(db.writeableDatabase , "1", "DefaultUser")
```